# How to use a Javascript var as an ID for a div?

Tags: javascript, html

What I have is a function that that generates string that get stored into a javascript var. What I want to do with that the var is assign it to be an id for a div on a page. I've been trying to get the variable set as the div ID but I have some difficulty in doing so.

```
<script>
    var rand = "arandomstring"
</script>
<div id= $(rand)  class = "outline">
    <b>Some Sample Text</b><br>
</div>
```

Am I assigning the variable correctly? It seems that this makes the div `id = "$(rand)"` rather than `"arandomstring"`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to use jquery?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this variable? Changing the id of an element can cause a lot of issues later on.

Comment: When are you assigning the variable?

Comment: JavaScript is not parsed in attributes, you will need a template framework to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will assign the value of the variable "rand" to your div's ID

HTML Code:

```
<div name="arandomstring" class="outline">
    <b>Some Sample Text</b></br>
<div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    var rand = 'some_data';
    $(".arandomstring").attr("id", rand);
</script>
```

Comment: I want the div id to be "arandomstring" but it needs to get the value from the javascript variable rand

Comment: That should be $(".outline").attr("id", rand);

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put JavaScript inside most attributes in HTML - only the `onevent` attributes (e.g. `onclick=""`, `onmouseover=""`) and `href=""` (with the `javascript:` URI scheme).

Instead, use an initial `id=""` value:

```
<div id="temp" class="outline"><b>some sample text</b></div>

var rand = getNewId();
var div = document.getElementById("temp");
div.setAttribute("id", rand);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are optional, so `id= $(rand)` translates to `id= "$(rand)"`.

Also, you don't give Javascript in markup unless it is an event attribute like onclick, etc or href.

You can do

```
<div class = "outline">
    <b>Some Sample Text</b><br>
</div>
<script>
    var rand = "arandomstring";
    document.querySelector(".outline").id = rand;
    alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see looks like you are using jQuery. Here is how you assign this variable as an id:

```
<script>
    var rand = "arandomstring";
    $('.outline').attr('id', rand);
</script>
<div class="outline">
    <b>Some Sample Text</b><br>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Smartik/waoecL2a/